# Is there any better way to fill form input values in the above search form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**I have a search form like below with just one field**

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 
        'action' => 'CustomerController@SearchCustomers', 
        'class' => "form-horizontal form-label-left")) !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Customer">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Below is code in Controller**

```
$AllCustomers = \App\Models\Customer_Model
    ::where('Customer', 'LIKE', '%'.$Customer.'%')
    ->get();
return View('Customer.List', array('AllCustomers' => $AllCustomers));
```

**What I am trying ?**

When the form is submitted for search, in the view , I should be able to view the keyword again in the textbox. For that I am doing below.

```
return View('Customer.List', array('AllCustomers' => $AllCustomers, 'Key' => $Customer));
```

and now in the Form, I am doing below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Customer" value="{{$Key}}">
```

**Question**

Is there any better way to fill form input values in the above search form ?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: can I use something like this ? `return View('Customer.List', array('AllCustomers' => $AllCustomers))->withInput();`

Comment: I know that worked in L4, but I can't find it in the docs for L5. Did you try it?

Comment: using 5.2.10, not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct approach is checking if the key is present in request using input inline check `$request->input('key', null)`, if so it will return null, else return the key, check the code bellow.

**Controller :**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $key = $request->input('key', null);

    $allCustomers = \App\Models\Customer_Model
        ::where('Customer', 'LIKE', '%'.$Customer.'%')->get();

    return View('Customer.List', compact('allCustomers', 'key'));
}
```

**View :**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Customer" value="{{is_null($key)?'':$key}}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to plugin `withInput();` method ?

Comment: You don't have just inputs to send here since you want to send also `$allCustomers` so IMO it's not one of the cases you have to use `withInput();`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the droid you're looking for:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * My action.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return View
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        ...
        return View('Customer.List', array_merge(
            ['AllCustomers' => $AllCustomers],
            $request->only(['Customer'])
        ));
    }
```

The `use` line and the type-hinted parameter in the action method perform dependency injection of the Request object.

Merging `$request->only(['Customer'])` into your view params gives you the desired "with input" functionality.

**Laravel doc:** https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests

Comment: Are you sure that we should pass `$request->all()` in the form ? I just checked it **contains many things** which are **Not part of the form** and is **very heavy object**.

Comment: @PankajGarg valid point. I've updated the answer to use `$request->only()` instead.

Comment: Finally we are both on the same track. Isn't that ?